# Is it possible to increase the lifetime of a cloud function container?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

We are currently testing our app that uses cloud functions, and we really notice the effect of the lifetime of a cloud function's container. Since it's small app we would like to increase the lifetime of the container to a day. I appears to have a lifetime of 30 minutes right now.

Is this possible when using the Spark plan?

Comment: Why do you look for doing this?

Comment: I push notifications from my cloud function but they have delays which the firestore doesn't have for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud Functions does not provide any way to control the behavior of the server instances that host your code.  It doesn't matter what billing plan you're on.  Cloud Functions just makes its own judgements about how long an instance may last.